# Regex lazy on non-capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex, non-greedy

I have this regex:

```
(?:(?:AND\sNOT|AND|OR)(?!.*(?:AND\sNOT|AND|OR))\s)(.*)
```

What I want is to get the last key:value pair, example -

```
k:v AND k1:v1 AND NOT k2:v2 OR k3:v3
```

I want the regex to match k3:v3, and it does,
but it doesn't match the key:value in the next situation -

```
k:v
```

I need it to match the key:value pair even if it's the first one and there's no operators brefore...

update: key:value is not the issue here, I need it to match everything after the last operator

update 2: tried to do the following -

```
(?:(?:AND\sNOT|AND|OR)?(?!.*(?:AND\sNOT|AND|OR))\s)(.*)
(?:(?:AND\sNOT|AND|OR?)(?!.*(?:AND\sNOT|AND|OR))\s)(.*)
```

didn't work

Comment: Maybe [`(?:.*(?:AND\sNOT|AND|OR)\s)?(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/jAeS6o/2)

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer so I could  vote it?

Comment: Added and updated regex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit - My bad, `\K` isn't supported in JS. Here's an alternative one:**

`/(?:.*(?:AND|OR|NOT)\s+)?(.*)/` (group 1)

https://regex101.com/r/AyVV89/3 (Please check the matches on the right panel, for some reason group 1 isn't highlighted on the text.)

**Original post**

Per your last update (that wasn't obvious at all before you mentioned it):

> key:value is not the issue here, I need it to match everything after
>   the last operator

This one will match anything after the last operator, no matter what it is (and work without an operator too):

`/(?:.*(?:AND|OR|NOT)\s+\K)?.*/`

https://regex101.com/r/AyVV89/2

Comment: Javascript doesn't support `\K`.

Comment: You're right, didn't realize that. Will edit/delete my answer then, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

***Update***

As per comments, I assume you need to match last key:value pair along with its operator if any, and anything that comes after:

```
(?:.*\b(AND(?:\sNOT)?|OR) +)?(\S+:\S+.*)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/zyJ4MD/1)

---

What you need could be simplified into this:

```
(?:AND(?:\sNOT)?|OR)\s+(\S+)$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/JXXjWk/1)

- `(?:AND(?:\sNOT)?|OR)` match `AND` or `AND NOT` or `OR`
- `\s+` match any number of whitespaces
- `(\S+)` match and capture none-whitespace characters
- `$` asserts end of string

Comment: Your regex  is not working as expected: https://regex101.com/r/JXXjWk/2

Comment: Well are you seeking for `\S+$`? [Look at this demo](https://regex101.com/r/yniN74/1).

Comment: No, your regex is not including white spaces event if it's not operator between them.. look at my question again.. anyway S.Jovan posted the correct regex

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yniN74/2 it matches the last word, not everything after the operator... I need the operators to be the separator, not white spaces

Comment: So you need everything after last key:value pair? here `asd asd`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jAeS6o/5 Now it's not grouping the values, it selects the operators too

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, you don't need the first operator at all. Simply try

```
(?!.*(?:NOT|AND|OR)\s)(\b.*)
```

Comment: your regex is not valid